# .NET Dynamic DLL Loading and Security

Tags: c#, .net, security, plugins

In C#, you have the ability to dynamically load assemblies given a DLL path fairly trivially with Assembly.LoadFrom. All well and good for a static path. However, what if you want to load from a path specified by the user?

For example, if you have a plugin system and the user specifies the path to the DLL file in a configuration file, how would you guard against someone loading malicious code via the plugin system? In other words, if Alice is running a software package on a system that has a configuration file where plugin dll's can be specified, how would you keep Eve from changing the config file to point to her own malicious dll if she were to gain access to Alice's system? Does .NET MEF address this issue?

Thanks

Comment: How would you keep Eve from changing the assembly file itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does .NET MEF address this issue?

No.  There is nothing in MEF related to security at all.

> For example, if you have a plugin system and the user specifies the path to the DLL file in a configuration file, how would you guard against someone loading malicious code via the plugin system? In other words, if Alice is running a software package on a system that has a configuration file where plugin dll's can be specified, how would you keep Eve from changing the config file to point to her own malicious dll if she were to gain access to Alice's system?

This is really more of an IT concern - if a user gains access to another user's account, they'll have the same control as that user.  In your case, if Eve gains access to Alice's account, there's no way to prevent Eve from doing something that you want to allow Alice to do (ie: load a plugin).

The best option, in this case, would be to restrict what plugins can do *as a whole* - which can be handled via [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx), as there are options provided in MAF for isolation.  However, this framework is far more complicated to use and implement then MEF.

Comment: It's true that if a malicious user gains access to the system it's an IT concern, but for someone writing software for critical systems, you don't want your system to be the one that gets exploited when the first line of defense (IT) fails.

Comment: Let's say you have a plugin API in an unmanaged language like C++. What's to stop somebody from implementing the API and having a memory leak in a loop that eventually takes the system down? 

Could assembly signing be used to ensure that you know who wrote the assembly you're loading?

Comment: @ChrisBush You could use signing to make sure that the assemblies are signed, and check the signer.  That adds another level in there of potential safety.

Comment: @ChrisBush FYI - That will, potentially, also work with MEF, as you could only add signed and known assemblies to the catalog.

Comment: @ChrisBush I'm at loss of your comment - if malicious user can modify files on user's machine (especially once that can only be changed by admin) I don't think you can do much about. What other line of defense you plan to have when your code no longer being run as it is replaced by attacker's one?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially this question have nothing to do with .Net and consists of 2 questions:

- how one prevents user from willingly running malicious code? - you don't
- how one prevents other regular user from changing configuration files for this user? - you store per-user configuration in per-user accessible location (default user's folder is perfect place). You can't protect from box admin changing anyone's configuration/binaries.

Comment: Not a useful answer. See my first comment on Reed's answer.

Comment: @ChrisBush You are breaking the [first law of computer security](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx) once that has been breached, there is nothing you can really do to make it "secure" only "difficult" so you are not the low hanging fruit. Is that what you want? it's ok if it is, just as long as you are aware of that fact.